# Shadow and Overload Is Nothing

Tags: vb.net

I have two classes

```
Class Unit
    Property People As List(Of People)
End Class

Class EmployeeUnit
    Inherits Unit
    Shadows Property People As List(Of Employee)
End class
```

Then I want to check if there's a list of people

```
unit.People IsNot Nothing
```

But when unit is defined as this

```
Dim unit As Unit = New EmployeeUnit With {.People = employeeList}
```

[`unit.People IsNot Nothing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/isnot-operator) returns [`False`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/boolean-data-type).

I've tried [`Overloads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/overloads) instead of [`Shadows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/shadows) but it results in [`False`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/boolean-data-type) still.

Is there a way to do this without [casting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/widening-and-narrowing-conversions) `unit` to `EmployeeUnit`?

Comment: Why you want to shadow or overload that property at all?

Comment: Because all people must not be employees (whom are people (most, as of 2017)).